# Django and angular setup with output hashing enabled

Tags: django, angular, web-applications

I have setup my django and angular 9 application by following this post: https://medium.com/swlh/django-angular-4-a-powerful-web-application-60b6fb39ef34 I want to use output hashing to avoid problems with resource caching by browser.

Is there a way. Perhaps by using wildcards to match a particular type of file eg. style.*.css!! Or set header on all such files to not to cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this storage class instead, then collectstatic will add hashes to filenames:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage